# Sorting with StupidTable JS and Date Columns

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sorting

I am using StupidTable JS to sort my table columns. Works great. However most of my columns sort with

```
data-sort='string'
```

and now I have a DATE column I need to sort. Not sure how to do this. The info is fed from a database so I believe I need some function. The format each date is in is

```
dd-Mon-yyyy ex: 12-MAY-2015 or 25-JUL-2014
```

??

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the rendering of the HTML, you can sort on the timestamp while still displaying the pretty date.

https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin#data-with-multiple-representationspredefined-order

Otherwise you'll need to create a custom sort function.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-sort="string">Name</th>
      <th data-sort="int">Birthday</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe McCullough</td>
      <td data-sort-value="672537600">April 25, 1991</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Clint Dempsey</td>
      <td data-sort-value="416016000">March 9, 1983</td>
    </tr>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort by **int** after converting the date string to an time-stamp (integer).

From the [Stupid-table](http://joequery.github.io/Stupid-Table-Plugin/) docs:

> The plugin internally recognizes "int", "string", "string-ins" (case-insensitive) and "float", so simple data tables will take very little effort on your part.

```
var dateString = '12-MAY-2015'
var date = new Date(dateString).getTime()
// 1431385200000
```

Then use `data-sort='int'` on your th elements.

---

**Or you could use a custom function:**

> These data types will be sufficient for many simple tables. However, if you need different data types for sorting, you can easily create your own!

```
<th data-sort="date">Date</th>

var table = $("table").stupidtable({
  "date": function(a,b){
    // Get these into date objects for comparison.
    aDate = new Date(a);
    bDate = new Date(b);
    return aDate - bDate;
  }
});
```

*<sup>Note: above code not tested</sup>*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and fixed it as follows:

```html
<td><span style="display:none;">20150512</span>12-MAY-2015</td>
```

Like this in PHP:

```html
<? php
$ date = date_create (YOUR_DATABASE_FIELD);
echo '<td><span style="display: none;">'. date_format ($ date, "Ymd"). '</span>'. date_format ($ date, "d-M-Y"). '</td>';
```

I hope this help you!